# Противоречит ли шаблон проектирования фабрика второму закону SOLID принципов

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования, solid

В плотную подступил к применению шаблонов в проектировании и наткнулся на противоречие шаблона фабрика и 2 закону SOLID принципов, в котором сказано о открытости/закрытости (Open-closed):"программные сущности должны быть открыты для расширения, но закрыты для модификации".

Предположим у нас уже есть код(указан ниже) на основе паттерна(шаблона) Фабрика, в котором хранятся данные и отдаются в формате Json. Допустим, нам надо еще отдавать данные в другом формате. Мы на основе интерфейса делаем класс CsvEncode. Но как быть с фабрикой Notepad - добавлять туда метод public function getCsvEncode()

Является ли добавление метода к классу нарушением второго закона SOLID принципов?

Или в данном случае программист должен пересмотреть код и переписать его под абстрактную фабрику? Я только начинаю использовать шаблоны проектирования, а чтобы их уместно применять только там где нужно, т.е. скидывать на них ответственность выполнения кода, уметь создавать независимые библиотеки мне необходимо понимание. Может я неправильно понял шаблон фабрика в контексте SOLID принципов? Я видел что в методе фабрики иногда ставят switch case.И в зависимости от параметра возвращают экземпляр соответствующего класса - вот здесь то я и обнаружил противоречие, если необходимо создавать еще один экземпляр класса - то придется залезать в код и хардкодить

```
<?php
//я так понимаю что шаблон фабрика это как правило связь один к одному обоих классов проиходящих от заданных интерфейсов

//итак задача - у нас есть данные в виде массива
//необходимо получить из этого массива заголовок,подвал, контент
//массив отдать в формате json  и csv


/*
*это interface Factory  создающий другие классы
*
*/
interface Factory
{
    /*
    *
    *@return string| NULL возвращает заголовок 
    */
    public function getHeader();
    /*
    *
    *@return string| NULL возвращает содержимое 
    */
    public function getContent();
    /*
    *
    *@return string| NULL возвращает подвал|нижний колонтитул
    */
    public function getFooter();
    /*
    *
    *@return Encode возвращает объект для управления данными в  формате Json
    */
    public function getJsonEncode();
}

/*
*это interfaceс Encode для перекодировки
*
*/
interface Encode
{
    public function getEncode();
}

/*
*класс для перкодировки данных исходящи от класса,поддерживающего интерфейс Factory
*
*@property Factory $data
*/
class JsonEncode implements Encode
{
    protected $data;
    public function __construct(Factory $obj)
    {
        $this->data=$obj;
    }
    /*
    *преобразует данные в json формат
    *
    *@return string
    */
    public function getEncode()
    {
        return  json_encode( ['head'=>$this->data->getHeader(),'content'=>$this->data->getContent(),'footer'=>$this->data->getFooter()] );
    }
}
class CsvEncode implements Encode
{
    protected $data;
    public function __construct(Factory $obj)
    {
        $this->data=$obj;
    }
    /*
    *преобразует данные в csv формат
    *
    *@return string
    */
    public function getEncode()
    {
        return  $this->data->getHeader(). PHP_EOL .$this->data->getContent(). PHP_EOL .$this->data->getFooter();
    }
}
/*
*класс для перкодировки данных исходящи от класса,поддерживающего интерфейс Factory
*
*@property string $head
*@property string $content
*@property string $footer
*/
class Notepad implements Factory{
    protected $head;
    protected $content;
    protected $footer;
    /*
    *
    *@param array $arr
    */
    public function __construct($arr){
        $this->head=$arr['head'];
        $this->content=$arr['content'];
        $this->footer=$arr['footer'];
    }
    /*
    *
    *@return string| NULL возвращает заголовок 
    */
    public function getHeader()
    {
        return $this->head;
    }
    /*
    *
    *@return string| NULL возвращает содержимое 
    */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }
    /*
    *
    *@return string| NULL возвращает подвал|нижний колонтитул
    */
    public function getFooter()
    {
        return $this->footer;
    }
    /*
    *
    *@return Encode возвращает объект для управления данными в  формате Json
    */
    public function getJsonEncode()
    {
        return new JsonEncode($this);
    }
}

$arr=['head'=>'заголовок','content'=>'содержимое','footer'=>'колонтитул'];
$a=new Notepad($arr);
echo $a->getJsonEncode()->getEncode();//выводим массив в формате json
```

я еще только учусь использовать phpDoc , для простоты не использовал в примере проверки на значения, отлов ошибок(try{}catch(){}) и автоматическое подключение классов :) спасибо что дочитали

Comment: Я так понимаю Notepad это ваш процессор т.е. Само приложение если да, тогда ещё один вопрос почему процессор вместо реализации своей логики занимается реализацией логики фабрики? И если мне не изменяет память среди шаблонов банды 4 есть только 2 фабрики это "фабричный метод" и "абстрактная фабрика".

Comment: Фабричный метод делает только один тип объектов, а абстрактная фабрика делает семейство объектов.

Comment: По сабжу, вам все ровно прийдется добавлять точку принятия решения вопрос в том где будет свич, нет вы конечно можете извернуться и добавить в вашу простую фабрику логику поиска нужного класса динамической генерацией имени нужного класса что-то вроде $type = 'csv'; $className = $type . 'Encoder'; // остальная логика. А в случае если нужного класса не нашлось возвращаем Null-объект.

Comment: Только сейчас прочёл код... То что вы изобразили это как бы даже не фабрика это больше похоже на какую то разновидность строителя. И ещё не понятно зачем вам именно такое решение на сколько я понял код Notepad у вас является Request-object и он вообще ничего не должен знать а ваших Encoder'ах а эклеры ничего не должны знать а какой то фабрике... Они изготавливаются фабрикой и получают на вход Request-объект и или его данные от фабрики (данные от фабрики означает что фабрика инитит энкодер данными которые она получила от клиента, а не собой.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала сделаю небольшое лирическое отступление и расскажу немного о терминологии.

---

Вообще говоря, вы не верно трактуете паттерн "Фабрика". Фабрика - порождающий паттерн, в котором *создание объектов* поручается специальному объекту. Вот так выглядит самая простая реализация этого паттерна:

```
interface FactoryInterface {
    public function createInstance();
}

class FooFactory implements FactoryInterface {
    public function createInstance() {
        return new Foo();
    }
}

class GooFactory implements FactoryInterface {
    public function createInstance() {
        return new Goo();
    }
}


class Client {
    private $factory;

    public function __construct(FactoryInterface $factory) {
        $this->factory = factory;
    }

    public function doSomething() {
        return $this->factory->createInstace()->doSomething();
    }
}
```

Существует сразу несколько модификаций этого паттерна:

- [Абстрактная фабрика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))
- [Фабричный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Основная задача паттерна "Фабрика" (как, впрочем, и его модификаций) - *инкапсулировать логику создания объектов в одном месте*.

---

В вашем случае я бы не стал говорить о фабрике (да и о других паттернах), а вместо этого просто разбил бы объекты по видам ответственности, согласно [*Принципу Единственной Ответственности*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) (Single Responsibility Principle). Например вот так:

```
class Document {
    public function getHeader() {/* ... */}
    public function getBody() {/* ... */}
    public function getFooter() {/* ... */}
}

interface Formatter {
    public function format(Document $doc);
}

class JsonFormatter {
    public function format(Document $doc) {
        return json_encode([
            'header' => $doc->getHeader(),
            'body' => $doc->getBody(),
            'footer' => $doc->getFooter(),
        ]);
    }
}

class CsvFormatter {
    public function format(Document $doc) {
        return sprintf(
            "header;body;footer\n%s;%s;%s",
            $doc->getHeader(),
            $doc->getBody(),
            $doc->getFooter()
        );
    }
}

$doc = new Document();
$formatter = new JsonFormatter();

echo $formatter->format($doc);
```

Мне кажется, для решения основной задачи этого будет более чем достаточно. Кроме того, такая реализация следует упомянутому вами *Open-Closed Principal*: для создания еще одного класса форматирования вам не нужно менять уже существующие классы.

<sub>(В качестве упражнения можете самостоятельно проверить следует ли этот код остальным принципам SOLID.)</sub>

При проектировании главное помнить следующее: *паттерны ради паттернов - путь к большой головной боли!*

Comment: Проблема в том что многим шаблоны кажутся святым граалем программирования. И пока свои шишки не набьют не поймут где и что применять, а где можно и даже нужно обойтись без шаблонов.

Comment: @fens, и именно поэтому, те, кто уже набил шишки, должны открывать глаза молодежи ;)

Comment: fens все таки прав - наличия switch case в фабрике это ущербно для расширения программы. Также понял почему предложенный код в качестве пример больше похож на шаблон строителя

Comment: Dmitriy Simushev  - это потрясающе красивый код, который помог мне понять фразу  fens - Проблема в том что многим шаблоны кажутся святым граалем программирования. Я исходил из принципа что мне необходимо написать хотя бы 1 раз пример каждого шаблона чтобы понять как он работает, а потом уже перейти к framework Yii2 и видеть  вшитые в него шаблоны. А вы правы я все чаще понимаю что каждый программист обязан набить свои шишки, написать свою говноCMS, 200 раз изобрести велосипед, понапихать шаблонов куда не нужно, чтобы достичь вашего уровня понимания.